# Flutter Firebase Messaging trigger onLaunch

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I have a question, because I am not fully understand something. So I wrote a simple app, to try something, so I send a message from Firebase via Firebase Cloud Messaging. I use the firebase_messaging flutter plugin (7.0.3 version). It just does a simple thing to get the message and navigate to another page. My problem is the following one, the onMessage and the onResume function works perfectly, but when the app is terminated and I click on the notification the app opens but nothing happens. So I read the documentation and I found this
[image: picture]
The third row says, that the data is lost... Does this mean that I lost every data in the payload?
My code is here if it helps

```
 static final NavigationService _navigationService =
      loc.Locator.locator<NavigationService>();
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  Future<void> reqPermission() async {
    bool permission = true;
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      permission = await _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
    }
    if (permission) {
      _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print(message);
          await _navigationService.navigateTo(NewPage.routeName);
        },
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print('onLaunch $message');
          await _navigationService.navigateTo(NewPage.routeName);
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print('onResume $message');
          await _navigationService.navigateTo(NewPage.routeName);
        },
        onBackgroundMessage: _myBackgroundHandler,
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently asked this question on GitHub, see: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5098#issuecomment-783444919

> That was true for the old version and it required a native workaround. The latest non-nullsafety version firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.14 will work from a terminated state (unless you force-quit the app on android). The updated documentation is at https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#receiving-messages

Answer (score 2):

you can send notifiction and data with fcm it supports notifiction on terminated but not data. You can able send body and title in notification so if you want to need basic notification (which only has title and body). You can send it with using notification.
If you need more than that, you can use it with flutter_local_notifications package
in onLaunch.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

This is how to use tokens

```
_firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((newToken) {
      User _currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .doc("tokens/" + _currentUser.uid)
          .set({"token": newToken});
    });
```

and you can push it like that.

```
  Future<bool> sendNotification(
      {@required Map<String, dynamic> messageMap,
      @required AppUser appUser,
      @required String token}) async {
    String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    String _firebaseKey ="<your key>"

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "key=$_firebaseKey"
    };
    String json =
        '{ "to" : "$token", "data" : { "message" : "${messageMap["message"]}", "sendBy": "${appUser.name}", "messageType": "${messageMap["messageType"]}", "sendById" : "${appUser.userId}" } }';
    http.post(url, headers: headers, body: json);
    return true;
  }
```

FCM configurtion

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        //getNotificationMessage(message["data"]["message"]);
        if(message["data"]["messageType"]=="text"){
          NotificationHandler.showNotification(message); // Flutter Local Notification method
        } else{
          NotificationHandler.showBigPictureNotification(message);// Flutter Local Notification method
        }
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        if(message["data"]["messageType"]=="text"){
          NotificationHandler.showNotification(message);// Flutter Local Notification method
        } else{
          NotificationHandler.showBigPictureNotification(message);// Flutter Local Notification method
        }
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        if(message["data"]["messageType"]=="text"){
          NotificationHandler.showNotification(message);// Flutter Local Notification method
        } else{
          NotificationHandler.showBigPictureNotification(message);// Flutter Local Notification method
        }
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
    );
  }
```

This is background message handler

```
Future<void> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    // Handle data message
    final dynamic data = message['data'];
    if(message["data"]["messageType"]=="text"){
      NotificationHandler.showNotification(message);// Flutter Local Notification method
    } else{
      NotificationHandler.showBigPictureNotification(message);// Flutter Local Notification method
    }

  }

  return Future.value();
}
```

This is how i did it in my project

Comment: I would like to send in the data section the name of the route. Is this possible or not?

Comment: @Butch It's possible.I added  example to my answer. Maybe will work for you