# firebase messaging and firestore and flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to find a good tutorial on how to notify the users. I found a couple but there is always a missing piece!

I created an app where one of the tabs is a chatroom where anyone can reach out to you and ask a question. I also have another tab that says list all notifications that the user has received and can review.

Firebase Messaging works well, I receive notifications when my app is closed. When it's in the foreground (onMessage) it does not show an overlay notification, which I did setup...

My main concern right now is, when someone sends a user a chat message, I want the other user to get a notification telling them that someone sent them a message.

My plan was to save the notification (ie tokenRead: true/false) in firestore and then SOME HOW tell firebase messaging to notify the user. but how????

Please help! thank you!!!

Comment: You need to use a cloud function and either call it from the client when they send a new message, or have it detect a change on the database eg. a new message has been saved.

Comment: @GrahamD After digging around, that seems the ultimate missing step on my end! I was hoping to avoid costs as much as possible (it seems cloud functions is not free) so I guess I will have to find a work around for now...

Comment: Do the numbers on cloud function costs. There is a free quota. There is no free lunch though, you usually get what you pay for. Depends how serious you are.

Answer (score 3):

This method is what i used, every time user logs in it will check 'is token changed' then will update it on firestore with userId. If you want to send notification to that user you can use that token.

```
_firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((newToken) {
      User _currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .doc("tokens/" + _currentUser.uid)
          .set({"token": newToken});
    });
```

and you can post it like that, this what i use.

```
  Future<bool> sendNotification(
      {@required Map<String, dynamic> messageMap,
      @required AppUser appUser,
      @required String token}) async {
    String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    String _firebaseKey ="<your key>"

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "key=$_firebaseKey"
    };
    String json =
        '{ "to" : "$token", "data" : { "message" : "${messageMap["message"]}", "sendBy": "${appUser.name}", "messageType": "${messageMap["messageType"]}", "sendById" : "${appUser.userId}" } }';
    http.post(url, headers: headers, body: json);
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! this looks great but this leads to me configuring "functions" in firebase, which they are indicating that it is not a free service. I was hoping to avoid any preliminary costs up until it is necessary. So now I am looking to set up a local notification process. check firebase if there is anything new and pop up a message to the users.

Comment: I made  a bigger explanation for this question you can check it out, maybe will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703938/flutter-firebase-messaging-trigger-onlaunch/65705071#65705071

Answer (score 2):

When the app is in the foreground it does not show an overlay notification,but `onMessage` callback gets called. so you can handle new event in it and show notification on your own.

in the earlier flutter `firebase_messaging` package we have two callbacks. `onMessage` and `onBackgroundMessage`. you can use this two callbacks like this (according to the official docs):

```dart
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        _showItemDialog(message);
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
      },
    );
```

and the `myBackgroundMessageHandler` is like:

```dart
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    // Handle data message
    final dynamic data = message['data'];
  }

  if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
    // Handle notification message
    final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
  }

  // Or do other work.
}
```

For complete information read the docs: [flutter firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)

Comment: Thank you! that is what I had and you confirmed it. Now I need to send out a notification without paying for a firebase service, most likely need to do my own custom class